# checkbox.Visible = false; but is it stil there?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have a Datalist in C# whith alot of checkboxes and firstnames. When a button is clicked, first, all data in the table is getting deleted and for every checkbox that is checked, the ID is inserted in the tabel again. That works well.

The problem is when I just display certain checkboxes for example where firstname is John. All checkboxes whith an ID is displayed but only those that contains John are Visible. If I check a few more of the checkboxes and click the button, again all all rows are getting deleted and then my thought was that the checkboxes that is visible = false; Stil are there and are getting inserted again. But they are not...

Are there another way to do it so it works like I want?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetEmployee();
    CompareEmployee();
}

private void GetEmployee()
{

string FirstName = table.Rows[i]["FirstName"].ToString();
string qs = (Request.QueryString["search"].ToString());


 DataTable table = SearchPerson(search);
 for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
        checkbox.ID = table.Rows[i]["UserID"].ToString();
        checkbox.Visible = false;

        HyperLink hlFirstName = new HyperLink();
        hlFirstName.Text = table.Rows[i]["FirstName"].ToString();            
        hlFirstName.Visible = false;


        string FirstName = table.Rows[i]["FirstName"].ToString();            
        string qs = (Request.QueryString["search"].ToString());

        if (qs.Contains(FirstName))
        {
            checkbox.Visible = true;
            hlFirstName.Visible = true;                
        }

        phEmployee.Controls.Add(checkbox);
        phEmployee.Controls.Add(hlFirstName);

    }
}

private void CompareEmployee()
{
    int UserID = ((User)Session["LoggedInUser"]).UserID;
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table = GetEmployee(UserID);

    foreach (Control c in phEmployee.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (c.ID == table.Rows[i][0].ToString())
                {
                    (c as CheckBox).Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int UserID = ((User)Session["LoggedInUser"]).UserID;
    {            
        DeleteEmployee(UserID);

        foreach (Control c in phEmployee.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
            {
                if ((c as CheckBox).Checked)
                {
                    AddEmployee(c.ID, UserID);
                }
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the `view state` of your CheckBoxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `Visible` to `false` does not cause the checkbox to disappear into some void, it is still there in your `Controls` collection.  I would avoid using the state of your UI this way and instead handle the `CheckedChanged` event and set some internal data structure to tell you what your current state is.

Also, avoid performing two casts.  You can simply do

```
var chk = c as CheckBox;
if( c != null )
{
    AddEmployee(c.ID, UserID);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The checkboxes are still there.  But they are not necessarily checked.  From your description, it sounds like invisible unchecked boxes are causing records to be deleted.

Comment: Yeah, even if the checkbox's Visible property is set to False, it's still present in the control tree during each page load, and its Checked property will be False. But I think we're missing something from the OP. Maybe if he could post a simplified version of the code and markup that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: It dosent matter if the checkboxes are checked or not all the ID:s from the database are getting deleted, then, the checked checkboxes are inserted. But the invisibel checboxes are not inserted.

Comment: @user1007103: You just said "then, the checked checkboxes are inserted".  So clearly, it does matter whether the checkboxes are checked or not.  Use some basic debugging skills, like counting the number of checkboxes, and the number of checked checkboxes, and the number of invisible checkboxes, on your way through the loop.  Then after the loop, use `Debug.WriteLine` to show those totals.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a `;` behind your `if()`, essentially closing that statement: `if (qs.Contains(FirstName));` The following bracket is always executed. You might as well be missing code to hide the checkboxes, but that's not in your code above.

Comment: The checkbox and Firstname are Visibel = false; as default.

Comment: What Mario is trying to say is that if (qs.Contains(FirstName));
will not do anything since it is an EMPTY if statement because the semicolon is immediately after the condition.

Comment: Yes, for now, just remove that semicolon and test to see if it's working as intended now.

Comment: I tryed to remove the semicolon, now when I type a name the results are case sensitiv... (I dont want it to be case sensitiv) and the result are the same as before, the invisibel checkboxes are not inserted.

Comment: After rereading your question, I tink you might be confusing "invisible/visible" and "checked/unchecked". Could you recheck on these? Also, something different: You shouldn't delete all entries in general. Just delete those that should be deleted. Otherwise you might lose data in case of errors (e.g. a crash or system shutdown happening the wrong second).

Answer (score 0):

In C# I used this and it worked. Hope it helps!

_checkBoxName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;